# Should bikers keep one spare spark plug in kit always?

Tags: sparkplugs, spark-plug-wires

Question would seem like opinion based and likely to be closed. But I don't it to be treated that way.

My motorcycle is 2009 Honda Stunner 125 cc, already ran 59000 kms. It has started giving white smoke, need engine re-do (can't afford now).

It is consuming lot of engine oil. Mechanic says that sometimes engine oil get stuck on spark-plug tip and this shortens spark-plug circuit. No current will go in no matter how much you kick. To fix I saw on your YouTube I made gap between tip of spark-plus and its hook using a coin. This trick improved life of spark plug, but should I keep one spare in my kit?

Comment: It is opinion based, but what's stopping you from keeping a spare one?

Comment: keep  better tools than a coin in your kit as well, like a proper gap tool and some emory cloth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this more generically than what you're asking, but hopefully it will help.

In general, bring whatever you think you'll need. If that need is a sparkplug and you can fit it in your kit, bring a sparkplug. If you think you'll need a kitchen sink and can fit in your kit, bring the sink. When you said this is totally an opinion based question, you are exactly right ... but it is up to you and what you believe you can safely transport. There is nothing stopping you from doing so and it may help you get home one day. In your case, don't forget to bring the tools to change out the sparkplug as well.

Comment: Ohh! Right, I should have asked "is their a way to keep your motorcycle working in case of faulty spark plug for few kilometers?"